# Auto generated Dockerfile for Web .net core application

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, dockerfile

In my opinion autogenerated Dockerfile for Web .net core application is too large, but why? Why Microsoft decided to create it like this?

This is autogenerated Dockerfile when we add flag "Add docker support" during App creation:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["app/app.csproj", "app/"]
RUN dotnet restore "app/app.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/app"
RUN dotnet build "app.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "app.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app.dll"]
```

And in my opinion it can looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0-buster as build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["app/app.csproj", "app/"]
RUN dotnet restore "app/app.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/app"
RUN dotnet build "app.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
RUN dotnet publish "app.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-buster-slim
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
COPY --from=build /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app.dll"]
```

Why Microsoft decided to first - get the aspnet:3.0-buster-slim just to expose ports and use them later as final? It would be much shorter just to get this image as the last step as in my example. Also do we need double From for the sdk:3.0-buster (fist named as build, second as publish)? It's possible to add multiple RUN one by one as in my example.

Maybe there is some tech suggestions why they decide to do that?
Thanks!

Comment: The first image in the Dockerfile is the one VS uses for debugging (by convention, there's a setting to override this and use a specific named stage in VS 2019). Obviously you want as short and quick a turnaround time as possible for this.

Answer (score 1):

A `Dockerfile` is a series of steps used by the `docker build .` command. There are at a minimum three steps required:

```
FROM some-base-image
COPY some-code-or-local-content
CMD the-entrypoint-command
```

As our application becomes more and more complex additional steps are added. Like restoring packages and dependencies. Commands like below are used for that:

```
RUN dotnet restore
```

-or-

```
RUN npm install
```

Or the likes. As it becomes more difficult the image build time will increase and the image size itself will increase.

Docker build steps generates multiple docker images and caches them. Notice the below output:

```
$ docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  310.7MB
Step 1/9 : FROM node:alpine
 ---> 4c6406de22fd
Step 2/9 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a6d9fba502f3
Step 3/9 : COPY ./package.json ./
 ---> dc39d95064cf
Step 4/9 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 7ccc864c268c
```

notice how `step 2` is saying `Using cache` because docker realized that everything upto step 2 is the same as from previous build step it is safe to use the cached from the previous build commands.

One of the focuses of this template is building efficient images.
Efficiency could be achieved in two ways:

1. reducing the time taken to build the image
2. reducing the size of the final image

For #1 using cached images from the previous builds is leveraged. Dividing dockerfile to rely more and more on the previous build makes the build process faster. It is only possible to rely on cache if the Dockerfile is written efficiently.

By separating these stages of build and publish the `docker build .` command will be better able to use more and more cache from previous steps in docker file.

For #2 avoid installing packages that are not required, for example.

refer docker documentation for more details [here](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).

Answer (score 0):

By default, VisualStudio uses [the Fast mode build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-build?view=vs-2019&WT.mc_id=visualstudio_containers_aka_containerfastmode#debugging) that actually builds your projects on the local machine and then shares the output folder to the container using volume mounting.

> In Fast mode, Visual Studio calls docker build with an argument that tells Docker to build only the base stage. Visual Studio handles the rest of the process without regard to the contents of the Dockerfile. So, when you modify your Dockerfile, such as to customize the container environment or install additional dependencies, you should put your modifications in the first stage. Any custom steps placed in the Dockerfile's build, publish, or final stages will not be executed.

Thus, the answer to your question

> Why Microsoft decided to first - get the aspnet:3.0-buster-slim just to expose ports and use them later as final?

It's necessary in order to provide optimized `Fast` mode build and debugging in VisualStudio.